# Sencha Touch - Extending Store - constructor call

Tags: extjs

I'm playing around with sencha and created a list with a store and a model:

main:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});

Ext.application({ 
viewport: {
    autoMaximize: false
},                                                                                                                                                                 
name: 'Sencha',                                                                                                                                                                  

launch: function() {     
    Ext.create('Ext.List', {
        fullscreen: true,

        store: Ext.create('store.Test', {
        }),

        itemTpl: '{lastName}, {firstName} Age: {age}'
    });
}                                                                                          
});
```

store:

```
Ext.define('store.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

model: 'model.User',
data: [
    { firstName: 'Ed',    lastName: 'Spencer', age: 30 },
    { firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz', age: 41 },
    { firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran', age: 24 },
    { firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins', age: 76 }
]
});
```

model:

```
Ext.define('model.User', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    { name: 'firstName', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'lastName', type: 'string' }
]
});
```

To this point everything works fine.

Then I created a second store, which has another field 'age'. What I want now is to pass a parameter 'model' to the store to be able to "switch" between different models.
I tried something like this:

store:

```
Ext.define('store.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
myModel: null,

constructor : function(model) {
    myModel = model;
}, 

model: this.myModel,

data: [
    { firstName: 'Ed',    lastName: 'Spencer', age: 30 },
    { firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz', age: 41 },
    { firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran', age: 24 },
    { firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins', age: 76 }
]
});
```

and in the main file:

```
[...]
        store: Ext.create('store.Test', {
           model: 'model.UserWithAge'
        }),
[...]
```

But Google Chrome gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'getRange'
```

Any hints what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a lot easier then I thought.
Instead of messing with constructors or something like that it is enough to just pass the model when creating the store as I allready did:

main:

```
[...]
    store: Ext.create('store.Test', {
       model: 'model.UserWithAge'
    }),
[...]
```

store:

```
Ext.define('store.Test', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

model: 'model.User', //only set in case that model is not passed when created

data: [
    { firstName: 'Ed',    lastName: 'Spencer', age: 30 },
    { firstName: 'Tommy', lastName: 'Maintz', age: 41 },
    { firstName: 'Aaron', lastName: 'Conran', age: 24 },
    { firstName: 'Jamie', lastName: 'Avins', age: 76 }
]
```

});